# How to detect that DetailsView displays not a data but EmptyDataText

Tags: asp.net, .net, detailsview, emptydatatext

I have a `DetailsView` and few buttons on my page.

So I want to hide them if `DetailsView` displays not a data but just a value if `EmptyDataText` property.

How can I do that?

I found only one way - `view.Rows[0].Cells.Count == 1` because if the data is displayed, more then one columns presents. But I don't like such method.

Comment: I have edit my answer, Plz check ....

Answer (score 2):

Please try DetailView properties like DataItemIndex and DataItemCount

Answer (score 1):

If there is empty data text only in the detailsview, In the first row there is text of empty data, we can compare it .........

```
 if (DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text == "your Empty Data text")
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is super old, but this may help others:

```
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <style>
            .thingsiwanthidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
```